# Post on Facebook with VBA

Tags: facebook, vba, excel

How do I post on Facebook with VBA. I have gotten as far as selecting the text box and typing out my message but cannot find the ID nor the Name of the post button for a `.click` command.

```
Sub facebookPost()

    Dim IE As Object

    Set IE = CreateObject("INTERNETEXPLORER.Application")

    IE.Navigate ("https://www.facebook.com/?stype=lo&jlou=Afe3wPrM68LQTdWlY9f9URv9S0pNI16qGLueOAY2qMqi8l8pQXeBjYg5ZZGM5X-8tLZ3azAhqFYdTNHwimEShHL3xx5h-XUkFB4uvLOG0einwA&smuh=4150&lh=Ac88dT0PK0FSwJTV")
    IE.Visible = True

    Do While IE.Busy: DoEvents: Loop

    IE.Document.All.Item("email").Value = "*********"
    IE.Document.All.Item("pass").Value = "********"
    IE.Document.All.Item("loginbutton").Click

    Do While IE.Busy: DoEvents: Loop

    IE.Document.All.Item("u_0_10").Select
    IE.Document.All.Item("u_0_10").Value = "Hellow world"

End Sub
```

Comment: And I thought VBA is dead :-) Why aren't you calling the Graph API instead of "screen browsing"?

Comment: i am very new to coding (little more then a week really). my friend VBA would be a easy place to start

Comment: To be honest, VBA is IMHO a dead language. If I'd start to learn how to code nowadays, I'd consider JavaScript as an alternative (through NodeJS). Makes much more sense together with with Facebook...

Comment: To find the correct ID/Class etc. you could use for instance document inspector of Google Chrome. The submit button doesn't seem to have id it only has class..

Comment: It's in one way a dead language, however, you can find yourself in a job needing a LOT of it all of a sudden as I have discovered. For me personally, just an IMHO, the language isn't **that** important but **how** you learn. If you can get the concepts, the way of thinking, looking up documents, finding answers etc you can port that to any other language. I avoided coding jobs as I wasn't a 'real coder' but as friends told me you don't memorize the language, you have a way of solving problems and finding solutions... It's true!

Comment: i have tried all i can and am completely lost. how do i get VBA to click this damn button -.-

I can find it class and i know to do a getElementByclass (""), but nothing i try selects the button or clicks it

Comment: @Tobi VBA might be dead language, but IMHO it's still useful and I personally recommend to use for couple reasons - 1. It's got a graphical interface that is easy to control and helps you understand coding concepts (object model) where in for ex. C has pretty steep learning curve. 2. If you work in almost any firm, they nowadays use MS Office tools and it's a great asset to be able to automate routine work without heavy duty coding and without costly tools.

Comment: I'd never recommend C for a beginner... And using VBA in the web environment is just a wrong choice IMHO. To use it in Office macros is fine with me, as you don't have any real other choice. But for this purpose, it's just a bad decision. Especially, when there are some APIs which directly support the OPs use case, instead of having a construct where you remotely control your browser.

Answer (score -1):

Try this code. I have copied this from somewhere. Hope this will help

```
Private Sub Facebook_Login_Automate()
    'Declare Variables used in Code
    Dim InetApp As Object
    Dim TagsArray As Object
    Dim TagField As Object

'Create InternetExplorer Object and Launch App
Set InetApp = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
InetApp.Visible = True

'Navigate to Facebook
InetApp.Navigate "http://www.facebook.com/"

'Internet Explorer Load Time Wait
Do While InetApp.Busy
    Application.StatusBar = "Application Loading. Please Wait..."
    Application.Wait DateAdd("s", 1, Now)
Loop
Application.StatusBar = ""

'HTML code is obtained from URL.
'Search for tag <input> and store it details in a object.
Set TagsArray = InetApp.document.getElementsByTagName("input")
idx = 0

'Search Fields Corresponding to 'Login id', 'Password' and 'Submit' button.
While idx < TagsArray.Length
    If TagsArray(idx).Name = "email" Then
        TagsArray(idx).Value = "xyz@gmail.com"
    Else
        If TagsArray(idx).Name = "pass" Then
            TagsArray(idx).Value = "xyz123"
        End If
        If TagsArray(idx).Type = "submit" And _
           TagsArray(idx).Name = "" Then
                Set TagField = TagsArray(idx)
        End If
    End If
    idx = idx + 1
Wend

'Click Submit Button
TagField.Click

'Login Wait Time
Do While InetApp.Busy
    Application.StatusBar = "Login in Progess. Please Wait..."
    Application.Wait DateAdd("s", 1, Now)
Loop
Application.StatusBar = ""
InetApp.Visible = True

'Clear Object Data
Set InetApp = Nothing
Set TagField = Nothing
Set TagsArray = Nothing

End Sub
```